# C# GoogleSheets API Inserting row to 2nd row?

Tags: c#, api, google-sheets-api

How do i insert a blank row into the 2nd row?

```
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest requestBody = new 
          BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
          requestBody.Requests = new List<Request>();
          Request r = new Request();
          requestBody.Requests.Add(r);
          r.InsertDimension = new InsertDimensionRequest();

          var dr = new DimensionRange();
          dr.SheetId = 0;
          dr.Dimension="ROW";
          dr.StartIndex = 0;
          dr.EndIndex = 3;

         r.InsertDimension.Range = dr;
         r.InsertDimension.InheritFromBefore = false;

        SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest bur = 
        service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(requestBody, spreadsheetId);
        bur.Execute();
```

This code adds 2 blank rows as specified in the sheets

I'm refering to page https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn

Comment: I haven't used googlesheets api but I bet you need to set the `InsertDimension` range, also what's the `IDR` for when you don't even use it?

Comment: Oops, yeah I set it as the IDR, which i renamed to DR for the object dimension range, but it still doesn't work. Not sure i'm setting it correctly

Comment: The error is Google.GoogleApiException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid value at 'requests[0].insert_dimension.range.dimension' (TYPE_ENUM), "ROW" [400]
Errors [
 Message[Invalid value at 'requests[0].insert_dimension.range.dimension' (TYPE_ENUM), "ROW"] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
]

Comment: If you have three items isn't the end index = 2?  indexes usually start at zero.

Comment: nvm, got it to work. i was missing a s after row